# oracle row level trigger collides with other triggers

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have a row-level trigger to update another table if a value changes. But on the table there are also many other triggers and an execution order cannot not be provided. So might be a compound trigger be a solution? But I cannot find in the internet the correct spelling for it. Here my current code:

```
create or replace TRIGGER my_trigger AFTER 
    INSERT OR UPDATE OF column1 ON my_table_1
    FOR EACH  ROW
DECLARE

BEGIN
    IF
        :new.my_table_1.column1 > 1
    THEN
        UPDATE my_table_2
        SET
            column2 = 1
        WHERE
                column_id1 = :new.column_id1
            AND column_id2 = :new.column_id2;
    END IF;
END my_trigger;
```

Comment: Sometimes I wish triggers weren't invented. Reading what you said, I have a question: are you **sure** you've taken right approach to the problem? If you have **many** triggers, it seems that you put quite a lot of processing into triggers. Why did you do that? Why wouldn't you move that into another level, e.g. procedure that "initiates" data changes (of all kinds - inserts, updates, deletes)?

Comment: that is true, but I cannot change it, it is historically grown. So above trigger needs to be executed as last trigger. I think a compound triger can manage that, correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do things in a certain order then do not do them in multiple triggers.

Either:

1. Combine all the triggers into a single trigger where you can control the order within the PL/SQL of the trigger body; or
2. Move from using triggers to a procedure.

So if you have two triggers:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger1
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF column2 ON my_table_1
  FOR EACH  ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
  IF :new.column2 := 'SOMETHING' THEN
    :new.column1 = 1;
  END;
END my_trigger1;
/

CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF column1 ON my_table_1
  FOR EACH  ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
  IF :new.column1 > 1 THEN
    UPDATE my_table_2
    SET   column2 = 1
    WHERE column_id1 = :new.column_id1
    AND   column_id2 = :new.column_id2;
  END IF;
END my_trigger2;
/
```

then you can change it to:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
FOR INSERT OR UPDATE OF column1, column2 ON my_table_1
COMPOUND TRIGGER
BEFORE EACH ROW
  IS
  BEGIN
    IF :new.column2 = 'SOMETHING' THEN
      :new.column1 := 2;
    END IF;
  END BEFORE EACH ROW;  
AFTER EACH ROW
  IS
  BEGIN
    IF :new.column1 > 1 THEN
      UPDATE my_table_2
      SET   column2 = 1
      WHERE column_id1 = :new.column_id1
      AND   column_id2 = :new.column_id2;
    END IF;
  END AFTER EACH ROW;  
END;
/
```

*(Note: the order would not change in this instance as one is a `BEFORE` and the other is an `AFTER` trigger, but you should get the idea that if you had multiple `BEFORE` or `AFTER` triggers then you can combine them all into a single trigger.)*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uggSZhvd)